# How to find the mysql IP address in shared host?

Tags: mysql, ip-address

I got the issue of PDO connectivity.I found the solution in this [thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/7901/)
to connect the mysql through the Mysql IP address.But I dont how to find the IP address of the mysql.Could you please help on this. I am in shared host.

Comment: "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" are not working?

Comment: You only need an IP address if the MySQL instance doesn't listen on a Unix domain socket such as `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`. Are you certain your database doesn't provide a Unix domain socket you could use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MySql is not hosted same server as your web host, you may need to check the welcome email from your shared host or send them a support ticket to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
?>
```